# Trino server is accepting connection, but is still initializing. How to wait until Trino is ready to receive queries?

Tags: trino

For some background, we have included a Trino server as part of our CI setup and tests currently fail while the server is still adding all of the catalogs. Currently, I have setup our CI to retry this curl command, but it does not wait until the server is fully started.

```
docker run appropriate/curl --retry 60 --retry-delay 1 --retry-connrefused http://trino:8080/
```

Trino responds before it is fully initialized so the tests start failing due to the Trino server error: `Trino server is still initializing`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check if a Trino server is still initializing, you can query information about the cluster by connecting to the coordinator. The following command is where you can see information about a cluster.

```
docker run appropriate/curl --retry 60 --retry-delay 1 --retry-connrefused http://trino:8080/v1/info
```

Depending on the state of the server it will return something like the following JSON.

```json
{
  "nodeVersion": {
    "version": "358"
  },
  "environment": "test",
  "coordinator": true,
  "starting": false,
  "uptime": "7.56m"
}
```

You may use the `$.starting` JSON field to determine if the server is alive and ready for queries. A simple ruby script that tries 60 times before giving is provided.

```sh
cat <<"RUBY" | ruby
60.times do
  exit if `docker run appropriate/curl http://trino:8080/v1/info | jq .starting`.strip == 'false'
  sleep 1
end
exit!
RUBY
```